# How to replace some text inside body without affecting existing tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, replace

I will explain with an example what I need to get done

```
<body>
    some text 
    <a href="http://somelink.com" class="some">some</a>
    <span class="test">test</span>
</body>
```

I need to highlight and add link to "some" and "test" in above html by replacing it with JavaScript , how can I do with out affecting other tags and "some" and "test" present in href and class

Note : I don't have access to to edit html of that page all i can do is put my script a the header

Comment: You want to add link JUST inside span element, right? Please explain little better - what is desired html output?

Comment: This code is for highlighting some keywords on a html page where i have no access to edit , they will put my scipt there what i have is only list of keywordsto highlight

Comment: okay and html will be provided by you? If yes, set a span class for all the words you want to highlight like <span class="hl">some</span> and put this in your jquery $('.hl').css('border','1px solid red'); I hope you get an idea...

Answer (score 1):

You can add a span around "some" and "text" with a specific class and then use jQuery class selector to manipulate as needed.

```
<span class="someSpan">some</span> <span class="textSpan">text</span> 

$( ".someSpan" ).css( "border", "1px solid red" );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    some text 
    <a id="link" href="http://somelink.com" class="some">some</a>
    <span id="span" class="test">test</span>
</body>

$("#link").text("some other text");

$("#span").text("some other text");
```

Comment: I cannot edit the html of that page , i need to get this done only through the javascript

Answer (score 0):

you can select them using the class and make your changes.

```
<body>
    some text 
    <a href="http://somelink.com" class="some">some</a>
    <span class="test">test</span>
</body>

$('span.test').text('Some new text');
$('a.some').text('Some new link text').attr('href',"http//newlink.com");
```